# Delay in change of Z-Index

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive made a simple periodic table for my assignment and i wanted to add a scaling animation to increase the size of the element im hovering on, for this i change the Z index of the element im hovering over but there seems to be a delay, where it scales up before changing the Z index.
Im very new to this and programming in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also i have never used javascript and would like to see if there is a way to fix this without using it but i understand that sometimes its necessary and will give it a shot.

```
#container {
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    
    
}

.num {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    font-size: 1vw;
    transition: 100ms color ease-in-out;
}

.element {
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
    width: calc(90vw / 18);
    height: calc(90vw / 18);
    border-radius: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 50ms scale ease-in-out;
    font-size: 3vw;
}


.element:hover{
    z-index: 2;
    scale: 2;
}


.element:hover .num {
    z-index: 2;
    scale: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

the element class is inside of the container div and the num class is inside of the element divs.

whole code:

HTML:

```
* {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#container {
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    
    
}

.num {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    font-size: 1vw;
    transition: 100ms color ease-in-out;
}

.element {
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
    width: calc(90vw / 18);
    height: calc(90vw / 18);
    border-radius: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 50ms scale ease-in-out;
    font-size: 3vw;
}


.element:hover{
    z-index: 2;
    scale: 2;
}


.element:hover .num {
    z-index: 2;
    scale: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.blankr1 {
    opacity: 0%;
    grid-column: span 16;
}

.blankr2 {
    opacity: 0%;
    grid-column: span 10;
}

.blankExtra1 {
    grid-column:span 1;
    opacity: 0%;
}

.blankExtra2 {
    opacity: 0%;
    grid-column: span 1;
}

.reactiveNonMetals {
    background-color: rgb(193, 233, 178);
}

.alkaliMetals {
    background-color: rgb(255, 152, 152);
}

.alkaliEarthMetals {
    background-color: rgb(255, 203, 136);
}

.transistionMetals {
    background-color: rgb(182, 182, 254);
}

.postTransMetals {
    background-color: rgb(174, 126, 220);
}

.metalloids {
    background-color: rgb(255, 241, 118);
}

.nobelGases {
    background-color: rgb(253, 189, 199);
}

.longer {
    font-size: 1.6vw;
}

.lanthanides {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(103, 103, 255);
    color: white;
}

.actinides {
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: rgb(166, 220, 202);
}

#container2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    margin-top: 40px;


}
```

CSS:

```
* {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#container {
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    
    
}

.num {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    font-size: 1vw;
    transition: 100ms color ease-in-out;
}

.element {
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
    width: calc(90vw / 18);
    height: calc(90vw / 18);
    border-radius: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 50ms scale ease-in-out;
    font-size: 3vw;
}


.element:hover{
    z-index: 2;
    scale: 2;
}


.element:hover .num {
    z-index: 2;
    scale: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.blankr1 {
    opacity: 0%;
    grid-column: span 16;
}

.blankr2 {
    opacity: 0%;
    grid-column: span 10;
}

.blankExtra1 {
    grid-column:span 1;
    opacity: 0%;
}

.blankExtra2 {
    opacity: 0%;
    grid-column: span 1;
}

.reactiveNonMetals {
    background-color: rgb(193, 233, 178);
}

.alkaliMetals {
    background-color: rgb(255, 152, 152);
}

.alkaliEarthMetals {
    background-color: rgb(255, 203, 136);
}

.transistionMetals {
    background-color: rgb(182, 182, 254);
}

.postTransMetals {
    background-color: rgb(174, 126, 220);
}

.metalloids {
    background-color: rgb(255, 241, 118);
}

.nobelGases {
    background-color: rgb(253, 189, 199);
}

.longer {
    font-size: 1.6vw;
}

.lanthanides {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(103, 103, 255);
    color: white;
}

.actinides {
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: rgb(166, 220, 202);
}

#container2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    margin-top: 40px;


}
```

Comment: Your question need more code, but more usable code, there is no Javascript nor HTML in your question

Answer (score 1):

Tell `transition` [which property to transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition), instead of transitioning all of them, e.g.

```css
.element {
  /* ... */
  transition: font-size 50ms scale ease-in-out;
}
```

If you don't, it's just going to transition every property with a new value, and because `z-index` is an integer value, and you can't be "somewhere between 1 and 2" when dealing with integers, it'll stay `1` until you reach the end of the transition, at which point it switches to `2`.